# Struts2: Using a variable value as property name

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

In my jsp, I have a label inside an iterator over a list of objects which have a "text" property:

```
<s:iterator value="survey.questions">
   <s:label for="d_%{id}" value="%{text}"></s:label>

   .....

<s:iterator/>
```

Now, since I want to localize the text inside the label, I added a property for every single language I support (textEN, textIT, etc...), and so I want the property name to be read from a local variable I previously set in the page, for example with:

```
<s:set var="loc" value="textEN" />
```

I cannot manage to do this, I tried with the following expression

```
<s:label for="d_%{id}" value="%{#loc}"></s:label>
```

But it prints nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED.

I had to add an id to the iterator

```
<s:iterator value="survey.questions" id="question">
```

and then directly access the property with this syntax:

```
<s:label for="d_%{id}" value="%{#question[#loc]}"/>
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Don't forget you can "accept" this answer by clicking the tick mark to the left. That's how we mark questions as resolved here. Self answers are welcome, so thanks for adding it!

Comment: Oops! I didn't know the tick mark thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must put the string into single quotes to stop struts from take this text as a variable name:

```
<s:set var="loc" value="'textEN'"/>
```

Now your `%{#loc}` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm sorry, it doesn't work. I tried your solution but it prints "textEN" and not the value of the textEN property...

Comment: I you put the textEn between quotation marks, it will print the string, not the property value. Are you sure you have the textEn attribute in your action, with a getter method? You could try adding in your jsp this property: <s:property value="textEn"/> to make sure there is some value going to the JSP page.

Comment: @CSoft If you want to use the build in translation possibilietes from struts you should use the `<s:text>` tag. The `value` attribute of the `<s:label>` element can also be replaced with the content, like so: `<s:label><s:text name="textEN"/></s:label>`

Comment: The problem is that I cannot hard-code the "textEN" property name, but I have to provide the property name reading it from a local variable, because the property name depends from the locale.